# How to know what item is selected ina recyclerview via checkbox?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview, clean-architecture

I have a question related to `recyclerview` and I would like to know how can I recognize what element is selected from a `recyclerview` whose items has a checkbox each one.

I am using clean architecture and one of my layouts has an spinner where I can select a city and i make an `http` post request and the response are all the offices in this city. I take all this offices and insert in my layout but all this items has a check box each one and I have to recognize which office I selected and I only can choose one of them.

How can I recognize which item is selected and how can I make to force user to only select one of them?

Comment: post code to let people help u..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple logic for that,
Generally i used to store Recyclerview index for that,we can use SetChecked listener on checkbox in recyclerview adapter, when you check any checkbox, store position value in any variable and after that you can get value from list or array which is used to store all offices data of this particular index.